# add 20px to auto width using only php and html (no java script what so ever)

Tags: php, html, width

I have many template files that I summon using the php method

`<?php if(!$root) for($i=count(explode("/",$_SERVER["PHP_SELF"]));$i>2;$i--) $root .= "../"; ?> 
<?php include ($root.'/listitems/item.hta'); ?>`

I Have a list of items using this method. One of those items needs (2) behind it to show how many of it you need. The problem is that format within the template file will put my number (2) on the next line if I add it behind my template and it will not show right behind my item on the same line.

This does not work:

`<div style="width: 400px ; float: left;">
    <?php include ($root.'/listitems/item.hta'); ?><div style="display: (any method);"><span>2</span></div>
</div>`

I came up with a solution using float: right; using a class that does this for me called "right"

`<div style="width: 400px ; float: left;">
                <div class="right" style="display: inline;"><span>2</span></div><?php include ($root.'/listitems/item.hta'); ?>
            </div>`

The problem with this is that it is way to far to the right.

When I change the width to auto instead of 400px I will have the (2) appear in between my icon image and my text, with my text flowing over to the next line. Somehow the format of my template is messing up the auto width property.

template:

`<div class="iconreagent">
    <a href="/listingpage.html#item" target="_blank">
        <img src="item image link.jpg"  class="itemicon">
        <div class="reagent_encader"></div>
    </a>

</div>

<div><b class="white">item</b></div>`

As this is all displayed in a div that loads different contents as I request it java-script will not work proper.

Is there a way to add 20px to the automated width using only PHP or HTML code
like shown underneath with a working code and not the nonworking as I am showing?

`width: <?php auto + 20px ; ?>;`

All I need is some extra width that would replace the 400px to make it look like it is regular inline text at the end of my line. I could set every template manually, but I use this template to often and I don't know how it will effect users on a different computer.
java script methods will NOT work as I have tried to trigger some simple stuff from that location which should have been impossible to fail unless javascript is not responding anymore.(something complicated that has to do with synchronization)

CSS classes used:

```
.itemicon {  //contains actual item icon image

    position: absolute;
    margin-left:-10px;
    margin-top:3px;
    top: -2px;
    left: 10px;
}

.iconreagent { //box that contain the icon image with border image

    margin-right:0px;
    width:26px;
    height:26px;
    position:relative;
    float: left;
}

.reagent_encader { //this is background image that acts as a non-glowing border

    background: url(border image link.png) no-repeat center transparent;
    background-size: 100% 100%;
    height: 22px;
    position: relative;
    top: -2px;
    width: 22px;
    left: -2px;
}
.reagent_encader:hover { //this is background image that acts as a non-glowing border when you hover
    background:url(glowing border image link.png) no-repeat center !important;
}

.white{ color:#f7ebd6 !important; }
```

link to actual page: http://mithcreations.atspace.eu/reagents.html#CopperBar

Comment: I had answer Ashkan Arefi answer 
"margin-right: -20px;" means "width = auto + 20px;" this was partialy usefull. The problem with the auto width is still appearing without anything behind. however it does allow me to positon it behind the text more proper. I need to increase the width to fix the content of that box that is overfrlowing into the next line

Comment: @NinjaDevelopers as far as i can see the title says no script.

Comment: what i meant with that is no java script solution as it will not synchronize the java-script. will edit the title